# FireBase-Prevent relaunching app after pressing back btn at the activity called by onMessageReceived

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-lifecycle

From the MainAcitivty I call the

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class), Constant.something);
```

My Application is on foreground with the **ActivityB** and my device receive the firebase's notification. The onMessageReceived is called

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        openNewActivity(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
private void openNewActivity(String messageBody) {
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(NotificationViewActivity.MESSAGE_EXTRA, messageBody);
    resultIntent.putExtras(bundle);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , resultIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("TESTTTTT")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager  notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager ) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(1000, builder.build());
}
```

When I click the firebase's notification when my app is on foreground, the **activityC** appears. However, when I **press back button** on my device, it returns to the **MainActivity** instead of returning the **ActivtyB**. Therefore, the app calls the **onCreate** of the **MainActivity**, it seems relaunch my app. Is there any way to prevent it, I want when press back button, the app returns the the **MainActivty** (want it calls the **onStart-> onResume** instead of **onCreate->onStart->onResume** of **MainActivity**)

However, when I create the new project with the simple activities. It happened like I want but in my project I is not right. Sorry for my language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, above code is right. My teammate put the wrong code at the onBackPressed in activityC. That code calls the MainActivity and set the intent's flags are android.intent.action.MAIN and android.intent.category.LAUNCHER. It makes the app running wrong like I described above